# Slow SQL query maxing out CPU

Tags: sql, cpu

I've inherited a site to look after and have a problem with an sql query which is maxing out CPU when the job runs on the site.

Unfortunately, I'm a front end developer and although I'm okay with simple sql this is too complex for me. The problem appears to be in the second EXISTS and its connection with the main query.

Here's the code, it should gather a list of item IDs to send to a company.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this query?

```
SELECT mc.id AS company_id,
       mi.id AS item_id,
       EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1 
         FROM mysite AS m2
         JOIN mysite_order AS mo2 
           ON m2.mysite_order_id = mo2.id 
        WHERE mo2.mysite_item_id = mo.mysite_item_id 
              AND m2.company_email_sent = 'Yes'
       ) AS email_sent_before, 
       m.id AS mysite_id,
       m.mysite_code_prefix,
       m.mysite_code_suffix
  FROM mysite_company AS mc
  JOIN mysite_item AS mi
    ON mc.id = mi.company_id 
  JOIN mysite_order AS mo 
    ON mi.id = mo.mysite_item_id
  JOIN mysite AS m
    ON mo.id = m.mysite_order_id
 WHERE mi.avail_end_date <= CURDATE()
   AND EXISTS ( 
           SELECT 1
             FROM mysite AS m3
             JOIN mysite_order AS mo3
               ON m3.mysite_order_id = mo3.id
            WHERE mo3.mysite_item_id = mo.mysite_item_id 
              AND m3.company_email_sent = 'No' )
ORDER BY company_id ASC, item_id ASC, m.mysite_code_prefix ASC,
            m.mysite_code_suffix ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `wo` seems to be an underfined alias - but that would cause an instant error, rather than the CPU hanging - could be a typo in what you've pasted there?  Apart from that though, in my experience (certainly with Oracle), having the same sizeable table appear 3 times in the query tends to confuse the optimiser and lead to unpredictable performance.

Comment: It is a typo, should be `mo`. I'll take a look at the second part about the sizeable table being used 3 times, see if there's anything I can do to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks... I've posted a slightly more detailed suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Which database server are you using and can you post an execution plan?

Comment: Agreed, an Explain Plan will help, well, explain a lot of what is going on and where the bottleneck is :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using an inline subquery like this:

```
...
    ( SELECT m2.company_email_sent, COUNT(m2.company_email_sent)
    FROM mysite AS m2
    JOIN mysite_order AS mo2
    ON m2.mysite_order_id = mo2.id
    WHERE mo2.mysite_item_id = mo.mysite_item_id 
    AND m2.company_email_sent IN ( 'Yes', 'No' )
    GROUP BY m2.company_email_sent ) email_status
...
```

You could then join to that inline subquery, and look for whether or not COUNT is 0, as an alternative to doing those two separate EXISTS subqueries.

Also - and I'm making assumptions about the business logic here - wouldn't you expect to have a join to `mysite_company` within the subquery? i.e. you care about whether an email about the item in question has been sent to the customer who is making the order?  At the moment there's nothing in the subqueries that correlates to the `mysite_customer` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue is the second `exists()`.

Depending on what you're looking for, it could be replaced with `mo.company_email_sent = 'No'` or a join statement.

Even more ideally, you'd want to store the value of that `exists()` statement in an indexed field. It could be set using a trigger or using app-level code.